# Can I create a folder in www directory via phonegap/cordova in IOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, file, cordova

I want to download some static webpage files(including .html/.css/.js/.png...) from server into my cordova based app, then users can browse them in webview. So I need to create folders in www/ directory, how can I achieve it?

Comment: Did my answer below help you at all?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.
You can use `window.requestFileSystem` to obtain a reference to the local filesystem (which is the application data folder).

Here is the documentation page:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#LocalFileSystem

Example functions would be:

- `directory.getFile`
- `filewriter.write(...)`

You then can create directories in there as well.
Like this for example:

```
fileSystem.getDirectory(dirName, {create:true})
```

etc. etc. ;)